# Can't set up virtual environment or see if Anaconda is installed, can't access bash folder, 'command not found'

Tags: python, conda

I am on a mac. the terminal window doesn't seem to be able to access my bin or bash folder anymore, I'm not sure.

In the terminal window I am typing 'conda --version' to determine which version of Anaconda I have installed but I get the message "-bash: conda: command not found" - Also when I am in Atom, and am using the python text editor and I'm trying to create a virtual environment, I type 'sudo conda create --name myDjangoEnv django' and I get the same message, 'sudo: conda: command not found'. I used sudo because otherwise it would not let me set up a virtual environment. I thought I had to enter a password to set up a virtual environment on a mac, and it worked yesterday. I think I edited the bash profile when I set up the virtual environment.

I was able to do all of this yesterday, when I typed 'conda --version' in my terminal I got the version of anaconda I installed, and I was able to update the version of anaconda. And in the python editor in Atom, when I typed ''sudo conda create --name myDjangoEnv django'-it set up a virtual environment. I was also able to update to the latest version of django.

Does anyone know what is going on? I'm pretty new to all of this stuff. Should I reinstall Atom, Anaconda, django, and Python? Perhaps, I didn't install it to the right location? Is it easier to run all these programs on windows 10? Thanks for any help.

atom is installed in: Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/Downloads

django: there's no .app for django so its hard to tell where its installed. some of the folders for django are installed here:
Macintosh HD /Users/myusername/newproject/newenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
or another django folder's location is here:
Macintosh HD /Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bokeh/server

python: there are so many python folders, 1 python 3.8 folder's location is:
Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/lxml-4.5.2-py38h63b7cb6_0/lib

Anaconda: Macintosh HD/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3

Comment: I saw something which said if your getting the “CommandNotFound" Error: "Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda" activate'. And, to initialize your shell, run: source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh and then: 
conda activate my_env   - could this work? Is the problem that i need to properly configure my shell  to use 'conda" activate'? I tried to run source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh - but I get no such file or directory

Comment: Have you made any changes since it last worked which could have lead to this?

Comment: yeah I should probably close this forum I was able to set up the virtual env by pasting: PATH=/Users/aleong/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH , but I still get the NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path

Comment: You should consider reinstalling Anaconda. Be careful with the PATH, the Anaconda FAQ section on [installing Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda) says _When installing Anaconda, we recommend that you do not add Anaconda to the Windows PATH because this can interfere with other software. Instead, open Anaconda with the Start Menu and select Anaconda Prompt, or use Anaconda Navigator (Start Menu - Anaconda Navigator)._

Comment: is this true for Mac as well as I am on a Mac not Windows

Comment: _is this true for Mac as well as I am on a Mac not Windows_ Yes, in that case the relevant quote is _We do not recommend adding Anaconda to the PATH manually. During installation, you will be asked “Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init?” We recommend “yes”. If you enter “no”, then conda will not modify your shell scripts at all. In order to initialize after the installation process is done, first run source <path to conda>/bin/activate and then run conda init._